# Pairs of trig functions: Pythagorean identities and derivatives

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, intuition

Or, "Why do the six trig functions split up into three pairs of best friends?"

There are three Pythagorean identities:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x &= 1\\
\tan^2 x + 1 &= \sec^2 x \\
\cot^2 x + 1 &= \csc^2 x
\end{align*}
$$

And the derivatives of our trig functions are:

\begin{array}{c | c}
f(x) & f'(x) \\ \hline
\sin x & \cos x \\
\tan x & \sec^2 x \\
\sec x & \sec x \tan x 
\end{array}

(where the derivatives of cofunctions are given by $\frac{d}{dx}[f(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)] = - f'(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$ via the chain rule, giving e.g. $\frac{d}{dx}[\cot x] = -\csc^2 x$).

I am curious: Is there any reason that sine and cosine, secant and tangent, and cosecant and cotangent like to hang out in those particular pairs so much?

Or, put another way: Given the Pythagorean identities, is it possible to see that the same pairs of trig functions will hang out together when it comes to differentiating, as well? I guess starting from the derivatives of trig functions would be OK too.

Comment: It is casual in the period $]-\pi,\pi[$ and perhaps because of the periodicity in relation with the cercle.

Comment: Those three Pythagorean identities are really just one.

Comment: @amd I know. But they illustrate the pairing.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$, $g$ satisfy the "Pythagorean" identity $f(x)^2+g(x)^2=1$, then $f\,f'+g\,g'=0$. This gives a relation between $f$, $g$ and its derivatives, but not necessarily like the ones for the trigonometric functions. For instance, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we have 
$$f'(x)=1,\quad g'(x)=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

Comment: This is a nice observation, and does give a relationship between ratios of derivatives and ratios of the functions, whether we have $f^2 + g^2 = 1$ or $f^2 - g^2 = 1$.